# Get exit status of background processes in bash

Tags: bash, parallel-processing, background-process, exit-code

I have tried multiple different ways to retrieve the exit status of a background process:

1. Capture pid of each background process, store in an array and then wait for each PID, get return status of each PID and store in a STATUS array.

Con: pid is not a child of this shell

2. tail --pid= -f /dev/null

Con: exit status is always 0 here

Looked around for various answers on stackoverflow. I am still not able to get it working. Can you please help and let me know where am I going wrong?

```
PIDS=()
STATUS=()
OVERALL_EXIT=0

# run processes and store pids in array

for target in ${target_list} ; do
    ./<script_to_execute> ${target} &
    PIDS+=$!
done


# wait for all processes to finish and then capture return status of each
for pid in ${PIDS[@]}; do
    echo "${pid}"
    wait ${pid} 
    #tail —pid=${pid} -f /dev/null
    #ps ax | grep ${pid} | grep -v grep 
    STATUS+=($?)
done

# looping through the status arr to check exit code for each
i=0
for st in ${STATUS[@]}; do
    if [[ ${st} -ne 0 ]]; then
        echo "$i failed"
        OVERALL_EXIT=1
    else
        echo "$i finished"
    fi
    ((i+=1))
done

exit ${overall_exit}
```

Comment: `PIDS+=( "$!" )`. If you don't use the parens, you're appending characters to the first element of the list, not adding extra list elements. And use `for pid in "${PIDS[@]}"`, *with the quotes*; run your code through http://shellcheck.net/

Comment: ...when you don't quote `"${array[@]}"`, it behaves exactly like `${array[*]}`, with all the bugs that imply.

Comment: and btw, not a cause of your issue, but note that all-caps names are used for variables meaningful to the shell, whereas names with lowercase characters are guaranteed not to conflict with the shell's behavior. From the POSIX spec @ http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html -- *The name space of environment variable names containing lowercase letters is reserved for applications. Applications can define any environment variables with names from this name space without modifying the behavior of the standard utilities.*

Comment: ...when reading the above, keep in mind that setting even a regular shell variable will overwrite any preexisting environment variable having the same name.

Comment: BTW, I'd also consider `(( overall_exit |= $? ))` as a shorter way to generate a combined exit status.

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions, editing my question write away. Can can you also please help to know how to get the exit status of background processes? I want the script to return the exit status of the background process, i.e. if one or more background process fails, script should exit with non -zero value

Comment: Your existing `wait "$pid"` approach is fine, if you just fix the way you're storing and retrieving the PIDs (as my answer shows you how to do). Maybe make it `wait "$pid" || (( overall_exit |= $? ))` to update an `overall_exit` variable at the same time without needing a second loop.

Comment: Uhm. **Don't** use `PIDS+=( "$! " )`. Use the extra space, **or** the array, but not both at once. (The array is the more robust approach when you're dealing with more interesting data than PIDs, so it's the one of the two I recommend). And changing the question in a way that invalidates prior answers is contrary to the rules here.

Comment: Let me underline again -- **changing the question in a way that invalidates prior answers is contrary to the rules here.** Someone else can't understand and learn from the question if they can't see the context the answer was written in. (See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295089/op-changes-a-question-after-it-has-been-answered)

Comment: Ok, reverting it back to what it was originally

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
PIDS+=$!
```

...doesn't do what you think it does. Consider:

```
PIDS=( )
PIDS+=11
PIDS+=22
PIDS+=33
declare -p PIDS
```

...if what you *expect* this to output is:

```
declare -a PIDS='([0]="11" [1]="22" [2]="33")
```

...you'd be mistaken, because what it *actually* emits is:

```
declare -a PIDS='([0]="112233")'
```

...because `+=` only appends a new array element when the thing on the right-hand side is an array.

Thus, you get a `not a child of this shell` error because the result of concatenating all your PIDs together into a single string isn't a PID that actually exists.

To fix it, use parens: `PIDS+=( "$!" )`

---

To provide an end-to-end example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# run four different processes; two exit status 0, one exits status 1, on exits status 2
# ...exits happen at delays ranging between 2-5 seconds.
delays=( 5 3 2 4 )
exits=(  0 0 1 2 )
for idx in "${!delays[@]}"; do
  (sleep "${delays[$idx]}"; exit "${exits[$idx]}") &
  pids+=( "$!" )
done

exit_status=0
for pid in "${pids[@]}"; do
  wait "$pid"; (( exit_status |= $? ))
done
echo "Combined exit status is $exit_status"
exit "$exit_status"
```

...properly exits after 5 seconds with:

```
Combined exit status is 3
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, trying out as you suggested and will let you know the results soon :)

Comment: Tried it, but still getting a message saying:  pid <PIDNO> is not a child of this shell and notice all processes exit with code 127.

Comment: Does that happen with the *exact code I gave here*, copied-and-pasted (into a script, not an interactive shell) without changes? We can't fix a problem when we don't have code that creates it.

Comment: With the sample code above it worked, let me see what I am doing wrong still.. Thanks much for your help!! This sample code made me narrow down to the issue! And also understood where I was going wrong..

Comment: Well, after hours of debugging figured out I had an extra wait, before I added wait for each pid. No wonder was not able to get this running before!! Thanks alot @Charles

Answer (score 2):

(This should have been a comment, but code gets formatted wrongly).

Looking at your full code it seems you are trying to implement a basic version of GNU Parallel in bash.

```
parallel -j0 ./<script_to_execute> ::: ${target_list}
```

I believe this will do the same as the full code (i.e. return an error if one of the jobs failed).